# Why does creating a Google Charts DataTable mis-interpret my dates?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have this client-side JS code:

```
var chartData = {
    cols: [
        { id: 'date', type: 'date' },
        { id: 'sessions', type: 'number' }
    ],
    rows: rowData
};

var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable(chartData);
```

Prior to execution of the last line above that creates a `DataTable`, the `rowData` variable contains this:

```
 rowData
 [Object
   c: Array[2]
      0: Object
        v: "Date(2015, 11, 28)"
        ...
```

After execution of the line that creates a `DataTable`, the `rowData` variable changes to this:

```
 rowData
 [Object
   c: Array[2]
      0: Object
        v: Mon Dec 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
        ...
```

Notice that my November dates have become December dates! Why?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's months start at index 0 for January. [See MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. And yet days and years are "normal"? Odd.